# Novel with Viking whose limb regenerated and he became immortal

Tags: story-identification, novel, regeneration

The book was written before science fiction was a true genre - hence my fascination with it and my unremitting requests to borrow it (from someone who is unwilling to lend out books becuaes 'they never come back')

I borrowed this book and then lost it. I read the first chapter prior. I must replace it but... searching for it is very difficult because I believe the character was called Eric(k) and Monty Python is swamping my search results.

He lived in a cave, lost his arm(maybe leg) and fell in mud so didn't die and regenerated his limb.

Comment: How long ago did you read this, and when was it written? Science fiction was comfortably a genre of its own since the 1950s at the latest, probably a lot earlier.

Comment: Also, if you’ve requested to borrow this many times before, would it be possible to ask the person from whom you wish to borrow it what the title is?

Comment: Hi Adamant. I managed to borrow the book 20 years ago after a year of pestering - it wasn't feasible to read it it where it was being stored - I read a single chapter and someone 'lost' it for me. I have searched for years but, because the title was something like= 'erik the viking' the search results keep swaping me with monty python ;)

Comment: The novel was written around the turn of the 20th century and that was what initially interested me most. I had read Erewhon and then, after research, Godwin, Bacon and Kepler's science fiction from centuries earlier. I try to find and read any 'early' sci-fi. My huge regret is losing this book.

Comment: Wait, the title had "the Viking" in it?

Comment: I think so - (also typo from ^) *swamping

Comment: OK, so by turn of the century you mean 1900 or so?

Comment: Sorry - yes about then. Maybe a little earlier.

Comment: So you cannot track down the person from whom you borrowed it?

Comment: Could it be *Eric Brighteyes*? Doesn't seem likely, but it is old.

Comment: Good shout but since finding 'She' I have found all Haggard's work. - sorry got to go be back later and thank you for everything. Adn, yes, the people who lent it to me don't remember the name either - they had not read it :(

Comment: Whoops! accidently put Eric Brighteyes in answers, not comments.  Then saw that comment was already there.  Answer deleted.

Comment: Any chance it is just "The Viking" by Edison Marshall? Only 1951 though but was the basis of the film "The Vikings" with Tony Curtis and Kirk Douglas.